# Python Embedding: PyImport_Import not from the current directory

Tags: python, c, python-embedding

using the next line

`pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);`

Only load modules from the current directory.

But what I want to load from somewhere else? Is there a neat way to do so?

`PyRun_SimpleString("import sys\nsys.path.append('<dir>')");`
Works, but it's a little bit ugly - I'm looking for a better way

Thanks!

Comment: Is really `<dir>` in the python path? AFAIK `PyImport_Import(<module-name>)` should be the same as the python's `import <module-name>`. If it isn't in the python path then *why* do you expect it to work? Surely you could do `sysModule = PyImport_Import("sys")` and then access `sys.path` using `PyObject_GetAttr` and call `PyList_Append` on it, but it seems even longer than using `PyRun_SimpleString` (although it should have less overhead since it doesn't have to compile and interpret the code.

Comment: @Bakuriu - I just found the answer - below

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just found the answer I was looking for at http://realmike.org/blog/2012/07/08/embedding-python-tutorial-part-1/

> Normally, when importing a module, Python tries to find the module
>   file next to the importing module (the module that contains the import
>   statement). Python then tries the directories in “sys.path”. The
>   current working directory is usually not considered. In our case, the
>   import is performed via the API, so there is no importing module in
>   whose directory Python could search for “shout_filter.py”. The plug-in
>   is also not on “sys.path”. One way of enabling Python to find the
>   plug-in is to add the current working directory to the module search
>   path by doing the equivalent of “sys.path.append(‘.’)” via the API.

```
Py_Initialize();
PyObject* sysPath = PySys_GetObject((char*)"path");
PyObject* programName = PyString_FromString(SplitFilename(argv[1]).c_str());
PyList_Append(sysPath, programName);
Py_DECREF(programName);
```

`SplitFilename` is a function I wrote to get the directory.

Comment: PyString_FromString has been replaced with PyUnicode_FromString in python3.  See link below for more details

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48849047/replacing-pystring-fromstring-method-in-python-3

Answer (score -1):

There is a good way because this is the way it is frequently done with site-packes.

```
import sys
sys.path.append(directory) # sys.path is a list of all directories to import from
```

or you use

```
os.cwd(directory) # change the working directory
```

before the import.

An other way is ugly:

```
import types, sys
m = types.ModuleType('module')
sys.modules['module'] = m
exec open('file').read() in m.__dict__ # python3
```

Maybe you asked for a C-function to do your work but I do not know one.

Comment: you meant `PyRun_SimpleString("import sys\nsys.path.append('<dir>')");`
Works, but it's a little bit ugly - I'm looking for a better way

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out. I read the question now. I just could not classify 'ugly' properly. Please see this as a negative example so you will not get any other such answers.