# Replacing PyString_FromString method in python 3

Tags: python, c++

TLDR; `PyString_FromString` doesn't work in Python3.5 so I need an alternative.

I am following an example for including python 3 within a C++ project from this python documentation:
https://docs.python.org/3/extending/embedding.html

Everything is working fine but now I want to change the line that reads:

`pValue = PyLong_FromLong(atoi(argv[i + 3]));`

to the following (I also no longer use i, that was from a loop):

`pValue = PyString_FromString("A string instead of a number");`

It seems the `PyString_FromString` function is no longer an option Python3.5 and I get the following error when I compile the code with g++:

```
main.cpp:559:60: error: ‘PyString_FromString’ was not declared in this scope
         pValue = PyString_FromString("A string instead of a number");`
```

Any idea on how I get around this? No matter what I look for I can't seem to find a solution that doesn't throw an error. I need to pass a string to my Python file and I have a string to start with already.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

[`PyUnicode_FromString()`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/unicode.html#c.PyUnicode_FromString)

```
if (!(pValue = PyUnicode_FromString("A string instead of a number")))
  return NULL;
```